# Get Path of installed Server in JAVA EE Server

Tags: java, path, location, wildfly

I need the main path from my OS of my installed JAVA EE Server (Wildfly) on which is the web app currently running.

So for example: If the JAVA EE Server (Wilfly) is installed at:
C:/Software/myApp/myServer

Than I need exactly this location.
How can I do this.
It could be that there is another instance for Wildfly, so I cannot use the System variable.

Comment: What kind of web framework you are using? You could use something like that `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`

Comment: I´m using ejb Bean, CDI....

Comment: Maybe I had to ask a better question. Where do you need the path? Inside EJB or inside your frontend like JSP, JSF, Servlet, JAX-RS ...?

Comment: No, I need the path in my EJB

Comment: CDI would be also ok

Answer (score 3):

Try `System.getProperty("jboss.home.dir")`.

Anyway, depending on the installation location is a bit of a design smell.

Comment: Ok but what is if I have two or more Wildfly installed on my PC? Is this working also?

Comment: Yes, the property is set by WildFly itself per process.

Comment: You're right about the design smell.  I can't think of a good reason to need this information in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your description of your question was not clearly, because EJB is business logic and not directly your web app, also when you deploy all within your war file. Because the EJB has no information about the request itself except it is a webservice with JAXWS.

When you only need the root path to your server and not the web app then you can use like @Harald Wellmann wrote :
        `System.getProperty("jboss.home.dir")`
and you will get the root path of your server.

If you need the path to your app then you could use for example

```
    this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

which will give you as standard behavior the path to your `/WEB-INF/classes` folder.

If you would use JSF, JSP or Servlets, then it is much simpler and you could get the information directly through the HttpServletRequest object with `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` like I wrote before.

And with an EJB with JAXWS you could inject get the HttpServletRequest object like this:

```
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

Comment: Thank you. But is wrote : System.getProperty("jboss.home.dir") correct if there are two or more wildfly server installed?

Comment: It is the root path of the server. If you will have different server then you will have also different paths. If you only have different apps within 1 server, then you will get always the same path. Try it and you will see what is the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Path to server dir (server/bin):

```
File inputFile = new File("file.xml"); // server_dir/bin/file.xml
```

Path to other server directories, "webapps" for example:

```
File inputFile = new File("../webapps/file.xml"); // server_dir/webapps/file.xml
```

Good way to get rid of the absolute paths :)
Tested on Tomcat, but hopefully it will help.